# I am using ibmwebsphere community edition 3.0v in ECLIPSE. windows 7 ultimate 64bit system. I am getting this error when ever I run an web application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere

Unable to create configuration for deployment: dependencies: null
org.apache.geronimo.common.DeploymentException: Unable to create configuration for deployment: dependencies: null
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.createTempConfiguration(DeploymentContext.java:211)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.initializeConfiguration(DeploymentContext.java:193)
    at org.apache.geronimo.j2ee.deployment.EARConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(EARConfigBuilder.java:661)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:255)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.KernelGBean.invoke(KernelGBean.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.MBeanGBeanBridge.invoke(MBeanGBeanBridge.java:172)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.LifecycleException: load of default/M-Banking/1.0/car failed
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:346)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:331)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(DeploymentConfigurationManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.DeploymentContext.createTempConfiguration(DeploymentContext.java:208)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.apache.geronimo.kernel.repository.MissingDependencyException: Missing dependency: org.apache.geronimo.configs/sharedlib//car
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.repository.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveInClassLoader(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:130)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.repository.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveInClassLoader(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:123)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.resolveParentIds(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:640)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.loadConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:342)
    ... 47 more